# Android - keep data after database update

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have an app which allows the users to add some data in the database.

If I wanted to make an update to the app with some changes into the database, after the update the database will be recreated and thus, the user will lose all the data he/she created on the app.

**Is there any way to "keep" the user data before recreating the database ?**

thanks !

Comment: Copy the old data in another database

Comment: Use 'Alter' in onUpgrade of SQLiteDatabaseHelper after checking version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `public abstract void onUpgrade (SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)`
Called when the database needs to be upgraded. The implementation should use this method to drop tables, add tables, or do anything else it needs to upgrade to the new schema version.

The SQLite ALTER TABLE documentation can be found here. If you add new columns you can use ALTER TABLE to insert them into a live table. If you rename or remove columns you can use ALTER TABLE to rename the old table, then create the new table and then populate the new table with the contents of the old table.

This method executes within a transaction. If an exception is thrown, all changes will automatically be rolled back.

Comment: Thanks Kirill, so the method `onUpgrade` must be changed everytime I want to update the database ?

Comment: Yes, if you want your users still have old data when migrate. Also don't forget to use database version number. There are lots tutorials about this and good docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html